# How can I start an application on a different system remotely?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, networking

I've got a situation where i have one system running a master application that communicates with slave applets on other systems, problem is, i can't guarentee that the slave applets will be running, nor that an operator can physically utilize the system to start the applet (and I'm also assuming they don't know how to use Remote desktop, these are minimum wage test operators)

**Is there an easy way to remotely launch an executeable on another system?**

security is not a concern here as this is a closed network.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're on the same network and have access credentials (username+password) to the remote computer, then Mark Russinovich's [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) is just the tool you need.

Answer (score 5):

WMI is your friend. See the following article which covers starting processes locally and remotely using WMI:

[How To: (Almost) Everything In WMI via C# Part 2: Processes (CodeProject)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EverythingInWmi02.aspx)

Kev

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Windows AT command](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565) to schedule tasks on a remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance of converting the remote applets into Windows services? They can be configured to start when the system starts; to retry if they fail; and to notify someone if there are problems. They're quite trivial to create with Visual Studio.

Comment: I'd like to know more about this, please update with more information, I had considered it but do not know about about services.

Comment: Also could this be easily implemented with WCF in a way that the master sends commands to the services and then subscribes to events/errors/etc.? I've JUST started looking at WCF, I'm more than happy to open a new question related to this to let you respond.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9.aspx. They're quite easy because when you create one, all the infrastructure is in place. Just override the OnStart method.

Comment: re WCF, I'm not certain, but I believe you can create WCF service that will start up when a request is received. Such a service can do anything, including run a workflow.

Answer (score 0):

here's a 2 step solution

1. Write a batch file to kick start
   the application/service in the
   context
2. Have the batch file on a
   shared network path which can be
   accessed from the machine would like
   to launch the application/service.

Honestly, I would suggest the PsExec solution by Piskvor. But you can try out this as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

another simple solution if you're not on the same network (accessing your home computer to run teamviewer for example) is to create a rule in Outlook (if you have it) whereas if you receive an email say from yourself, you can have it start an application if there are certain pieces of text in the message body or subject line, for example:

Create a mailbox rule: 
Step 1 - Conditions: From & With specific words in the body (from being your mail address and the message body: Start Teamviewer
Step 2 - Start Application (browse to the location of the .exe you want to launch)
Step 3 - enable that bad boy!

Obviously, you have to have Outlook open and accepting incoming mail in order for this to work.

you can tailor this to your requirements, ie: if Start Teamviewer is too easy, you can put codes or passwords in there too, so when the email arrives, it'll read the message, recognise the info based on the rule, and launch the application. :)

Comment: It is possible to achieve the said functionality by creating rules in Outlook but it then require that every PC must have Microsoft Outlook in it.