# Start gRPC Server from another application on remote server

Tags: process, grpc, remote-server

I have a requirement in my  project where I have to start the gRPC Server as a part of a project and the client will be on the local machine and server on the remote machine. I tried using below code to run the server, but the application errors out because of the code.

```
Process process = new Process();
                        
process.StartInfo.FileName = "{the file path}";
// startInfo.Arguments = "https://{ip address}";
Log.Always("pROCESS STARTS ******");
Process.Start();
```

The above code starts the gRPC server on local host. But the problem is  that my client is on the remote server. So, I tried giving IP address as the arguments (commented above) but it didn't work and even didn't let the application run successfully.

Is there any way to make the gRPC pc server run as a process on the IP address? Or is there some other way i can try to achieve this?

Comment: Could your question be rephrased as "How do I start a remote windows application using c#?"? (the "why" is not really relevant). If so take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717577/how-can-i-start-an-application-on-a-different-system-remotely) for a range of options.

Comment: yes,but using the IP address.

Comment: OK then - see the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717577/how-can-i-start-an-application-on-a-different-system-remotely) for a range of options.